# Given the sequence $\{X_n\}$ converges to $1$, show that the sequence $\{3\cdot X_n + 1\}$ converges to $4$.

Tags: real-analysis

I have tried to use the definition of convergent - for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N_1$ such that  $|X_n - x| < \epsilon$. I have also tried to proof this through induction, but I am missing some links here. Also I tried to reorder lim $\{3\cdot X_n + 1 \}$ as two separate limits s.t. $$3\,\lim\{X_n\} + \lim\{1\} = [(3 \cdot 1) + 1].$$ I'm not sure what method to use to prove this statement and am asking for some guidance here please!

Comment: Which definition are you supposed to use?

Comment: It looks like you've chopped off a piece of the definition of convergent. To say that $X_n$ converges to $x$ means that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N_1$ such that **if $n > N_1$ then** $|X_n - x| < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

We have that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N(\epsilon) \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $n > N(\epsilon) \implies \lvert X_n-1 \rvert < \epsilon$. However, $\lvert X_n-1 \rvert < \epsilon$ can be multiplied by $3$ to get $\lvert 3X_n-3 \rvert < 3\epsilon$. Then, we can change $3X_n$ to $(3X_n+1)-1$ to get $\lvert (3X_n+1)-4 \rvert < 3\epsilon$.

Thus, let's say we have a $\epsilon_2 > 0$. For $N(\frac{\epsilon_2}{3})$, by the above reasoning, we have $\lvert (3X_n+1)-4 \rvert > 3\frac{\epsilon_2}{3}=\epsilon_2$. Thus, for any $\epsilon_2 > 0$, we can find some $N_2(\epsilon_2)=N(\frac{\epsilon_2}{3}) \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\lvert (3X_n+1)-4 \rvert > \epsilon_2$, meaning $3X_n+1$ converges to $4$.

---

Basically, the trick I used here is to multiply the inequality by the coefficient of the sequence and then do $+1-1$ in order to turn the $3x_n-3$ into a $3X_n+1-4$. Really, this is a very short problem, but you need to notice that small trick in order to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary. Choose $N$ so for all $n>N$ we have that $|X_n-1|< \frac{\epsilon}{3} $. Then we see that for all $n>N$,   $|(3X_n+1)-4| = |3X_n-3|=3|X_n-1| <3(\frac{\epsilon }{3}) = \epsilon$. Then we get the result as we let $\epsilon$ tend to 0.

Comment: Your last line is unnecessary (and incorrect).

Comment: @ZacharySelk Isnt the whole point of showing a sequence, ${x_n}$ converges to some $x$ is show that for any $\epsilon >0$ we can find an $N$ so $n>N$ implys $|x_n-x| < \epsilon$ ?

Comment: That is correct. I don't know what you mean by "let $\epsilon$ tend to $0$" though.

Comment: @ZacharySelk I mean that since $\epsilon >0$ was arbitrary we can keep taking $\epsilon$ to be as close to $0$ as we want which is what needs to happen in order for the sequence to converge.

Comment: All of that is contained in "let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary"

Comment: My point being that you have a 100% correct solution, then you add an extra line that doesn't make sense. What does it mean for us to "let" a number "tend" to another number?